# Parent Form can't access Child Form Public Property - Winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, parent-child

I am feeling kind of stupid at the moment, because everywhere I read this is a normal procedure, and I just cannot find why I am not able to do it also!

So, the situation is the following, I have a Parent Form and a Child Form. The Child Form has a public property. From the Parent Form, i want to access the Child Form public property, and I can't.

My code is the following:

Parent code:

```
namespace myProgram.UserInterfaces
{
  public partial class ProjectNew : Form
  {
    public ProjectNew()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonSelectCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form f = new ProjectCustomerList())
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            f.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        this.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Child code:

```
namespace myProgram.UserInterfaces
{
  public partial class ProjectCustomerList : Form
  {
    public EntCustomer _selectedCustomer = new EntCustomer();

    public EntCustomer SelectedCustomer {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCustomer;
        }
    }

    public ProjectCustomerList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // --- other code ---
  }  
}
```

After the **using (Form f = new ProjectCustomerList())** i would like to do the following: **var sCustomer = f.SelectedCustomer;**, but when I do this, Visual Studio doesn't recognize the Child Form public property.

What am I doing wrong? :|

Comment: This is normal with inheritance, since f in your case is handled as a simple Form. You could typecast it to ```ProjectCustomerList``` to access the Property. The ```is``` operator is also useful.
```if(f is ProjectCustomerList) (f as ProjectCustomerList).SelectedCustomer``` or simply ```using (ProjectCustomerList f = new ProjectCustomerList())...```

Comment: @FrankM, you should put your comment as an answer; it's definitely correct.

Comment: one more mistake that would have been avoided by using `var`...

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal with inheritance, since f in your case is handled as a simple Form.

You could typecast it to `ProjectCustomerList` to access the Property. 
The is operator is also useful.

```
if (f is ProjectCustomerList)
{
    (f as ProjectCustomerList).SelectedCustomer =...;
}
```

or simply

```
using (ProjectCustomerList f = new ProjectCustomerList())
{
    f.SelectedCustomer =...;
}
```

seen var in other comments, works too

```
using (var f = new ProjectCustomerList())
{
    f.SelectedCustomer =...;
}
```

Comment: I already knew this concept, but I didn't associated it with the forms, which is a Class like the others, but... I was blind!  :)
Now that you mention is, it became crystal clear! 
Thanks so much @FrankM